# std::vector transform to std::map

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14

I have an `std::vector<C>` that I want to transform to an `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`, where the key will be the `category_id` and the value will be a vector of all winners for this category.

```
struct C {
    int category_id;
    int winner;
}
```

How can I do the above transformation? Shall I use two for loops one for the keys and one for the values?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and why it does not work. Also, please choose only one C++ standard tag.

Comment: I really don't see how this is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like that.

```
std::vector<C> c_vector;
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
for (const auto& [id, winner] : c_vector) {
    map[id].push_back(winner);
}
```

Comment: `map[id].push_back(winner);` is enough. No need to check if `count`>0

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```
//vector<C> C already initialised

map<int, vector<int>> Map;

for (auto& c:C)
{
    Map.insert(pair<int, vector<int>>(c.category_id, vector<int>(c.winner))); 
}
```

Comment: I think OP wanted a map where you can look up a category and get every winner in that category.